# New SVN Repository Structure and Porting Comments

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Is it possible to port over comments from one project to a new Repository structure?  Meaning is there some sort of comment file you can port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can migrate all repository data, including log messages and revision data, using the `svnadmin dump` and `svnadmin load` commands.  The `--parent-dir` option will help you control where in the new repository structure all that data is imported.

For example if you currently have a repository for `Project1`, and you want to import all that data into `MyCompanyRepository/Project1/trunk`,

```
# On the repository server...
svnadmin dump /path/to/repo/for/Project1 > dumpfile
svnadmin load /path/to/repo/for/MyCompanyRepository --parent-dir Project1/trunk < dumpfile
```

See the [Subversion book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate) for details.

Comment: well, that is if you did not delete the original repository on the server!  right?

Comment: whoops... yep, if you've already deleted the old repository, you deleted all those log messages with it.

Comment: what if you want to port to an all diffrent repository alltogether! ??

Comment: For example I'm wanting to port all comments and history from this repository https://xxx.xxx.com:8443/svn/sss/trunk/sssWeb to this one which is a completely new repository and structure I just created using Visual SVN Server: https://xxx.xxx.com:8443/svn/sss/sssWebsite/trunk

Comment: and the second link is an entire new repository /sss/ has really a real name, I just did that for posting purposes here.

Comment: Yes, that's what the dump and load commands do.  You can load the dump into a completely different repository.

Answer (score 0):

Once loaded as noted by Nick you can restructure the new repo with svn mv